# Python indexing into an list and getting an error I shouldn't be getting

Tags: python

I am indexing into a list like this

```
if first.Barcode == rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][0]:
    do stuff
```

- `first.Barcode` is a string
- `rcv_record` is a list that looks like this `[[],[],[]]` like so
- and `rcv_record_len` is the `len(rcv_record)`

it was working fine and now it says `unsupported opperand - on int and list` but 1 and `rcv_record_len` are both ints. Anyone have any clue?

Edit the way I am adding to this list is by extending a tmp list and then appending to rcv_record

```
tmp.extend([first.Cost*first.Qty])
tmp.extend([first.Qty])
tmp.extend([first.Name])
tmp.extend([first.Units_case])
#tmp.extend([(first.Units_case)/(first.Cost)]) << if this is not commented werid stuff happens
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
rcv_record.append(tmp)           
rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
while first != []:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if first.Barcode == rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][0]:
```

I am starting to think there is a bug or something. After uncommenting and commenting it the same error pops up on another line that has this code

```
if hasattr(first,'Cga_type'):
```

which has nothing to do with ints same error though

Also I am using pdb and stepping through the code and am copying and pasting the offending piece and it works but as soon as I run without the debugger it breaks.

I have edited out

```
tmp.extend([first.Units_case])
tmp.extend([(first.Units_case)/(first.Cost)])
```

and commented out the code where this is ever used or referenced and everything works as it should. This is to prove that the issue isn't with what I currently have but is with this new snippet that for whatever reason breaks everything. After these are added I get the weird opperand int list errors.

Here is the beast it's a wreck I know but this project just sorta fell on my lap.

```
if Type == 'burn rate':
       RcvRecords = []
       RmvRecords = []    
       while broken_item_len > 0:
           if broken_item[broken_item_len-1][0] == 'Chemicals':
              RcvRecords.extend(ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Chemicals.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Receiving').filter(Valid=True))
              RmvRecords.extend(ChemicalRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Chemicals.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Removing').filter(Valid=True))
           if broken_item[broken_item_len-1][0] == 'Supplies':
              RcvRecords.extend(SupplyRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Supplies.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Receiving').filter(Valid=True))
              RmvRecords.extend(SupplyRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Supplies.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Removing').filter(Valid=True))
           if broken_item[broken_item_len-1][0] == 'Gasses':
              RcvRecords.extend(GasRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Receiving').filter(Cga_type=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Cga_type).filter(Size=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Size).filter(Valid=True))
              RmvRecords.extend(GasRecord.objects.filter(Date__range=[From,To]).filter(Barcode=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Barcode).filter(Action='Removing').filter(Cga_type=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Cga_type).filter(Size=Gasses.objects.get(id=broken_item[broken_item_len-1][1]).Size).filter(Valid=True))
           broken_item_len = broken_item_len - 1 
       RcvRecords_len = len(RcvRecords)
       RmvRecords_len = len(RmvRecords)
       tmp_RcvRecords = RcvRecords
       tmp_RcvRecords_len = len(tmp_RcvRecords)
       tmp_RmvRecords = RmvRecords
       rcv_record = []
       tmp = []
       debugg = ''
       #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
       while tmp_RcvRecords_len > 0:
             if tmp_RcvRecords:
                 first = tmp_RcvRecords.pop()
                 tmp_RcvRecords_len = len(tmp_RcvRecords)
                 debugg = 'pop'
                 #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
             if rcv_record == []:
                 tmp.append(first.Barcode)
                 debugg = 'check barcode'
                 #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                 if hasattr(first,'Cga_type'):
                     tmp.extend(first.Cga_type)
                     tmp.extend(first.Size)
                     debugg = 'cga exists'
                     #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                 else:
                     tmp.extend(['',''])   
                 tmp.extend([first.Cost*first.Qty])

                 tmp.extend([first.Qty])

                 tmp.extend([first.Name])
                 #tmp.extend([first.Units_case])  << THIS PIECE
                 #tmp.extend([(first.Units_case)/(first.Cost)]) << THIS PIECE
                 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                 rcv_record.append(tmp)
                 tmp = []
                 debugg = 'herp'                    
             else:
                  rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
                  while first != []:
                      import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                      if first.Barcode == rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][0]:
                          import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                          if hasattr(first,'Cga_type'):
                              if first.Cga_type == rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][1]:
                                  if first.Size == rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][2]:
                                      rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][3] = rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][3]+(first.Cost*first.Qty)                              
                                      rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][4] = rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][4]+first.Qty##edited this
                                      #if rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][6] <> first.Units_case or rcv_record[rcv_record-1][3] <> first.Cost: << THIS PIECE
                                          #rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][7] = (rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][7]+(first.Units_case/first.Cost))/2.0##edited this<< THIS PIECE
                                      #rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
                                      debugg = 'first'
                                      import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                                      first =[]                                          
                                  else:
                                      tmp = [first.Barcode,first.Cga_type,first.Size,first.Qty*first.Cost,first.Qty,first.Name]#,first.Units_case,(first.Units_case/first.Cost)]<< THIS PIECE AFTER COMMENTS
                                      rcv_record.append(tmp)
                                      #rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
                                      debugg = 'second'
                                      import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                                      first = []                                         
                              else:
                                  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                                  tmp = [first.Barcode,first.Cga_type,first.Size,first.Qty*first.Cost,first.Qty,first.Name]#,first.Units_case,(first.Units_case/first.Cost)]      << THIS PIECE AFTER COMMENTS
                                  rcv_record.append(tmp)
                                  #rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
                                  first = []
                                  debugg = 'third'
                                  import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

                          else:
                              rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][3] = rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][3] + (first.Qty*first.Cost)
                              rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][4] = rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][4] + first.Qty ## edited this here
                              #if rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][6] <> first.Units_case or rcv_record[rcv_record-1][3] <> first.Cost: << THIS PIECE
                                          #rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][7] = (rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][7]+(first.Units_case/first.Cost))/2.0##edited this << THIS PIECE
                              debugg = '4th'
                              import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                              first = []

                      else:
                          if hasattr(first,'Cga_type'):
                              tmp = [first.Barcode,first.Cga_type,first.Size,first.Cost*first.Qty,first.Qty,first.Name]#,first.Units_case,(first.Units_case/first.Cost)] << THIS PIECE
                              rcv_record.append(tmp)
                              #rcv_record_len = len(rcv_record)
                              debugg = '5th'
                              import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                              first = []
                          else:
                              tmp =[first.Barcode,'','',first.Cost*first.Qty,first.Qty,first.Name]#,first.Units_case,(first.Units_case/first.Cost)] << THIS PIECE
                              rcv_record.append(tmp)
                              #rcv_record_len=len(rcv_record)
                              debugg = '6th'
                              import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                              first = []
                      rcv_record_len = rcv_record_len - 1
```

If you do a ctrl - f for THIS you will find all the snippets that create problems

Comment: Can you provide more of your surrounding code?  If you are getting that error on that line, then that variable is definitely not the type you think it is.

Comment: Ditto. Where is rcv_record_len defined and rcv_record?

Comment: print `rcv_record_len` before the `if`

Comment: Try len(rcv_record) - 1

Comment: Does changing it into `rcv_record[len(rcv_record)-1][0]` solve your problem?

Comment: Holycrap, inline imports. Please never do that.

Comment: I have no clue what an inline import is.
Also neither of those solve the issue. thanks though.

Comment: `import x; x.something` imports should be at the top of your file, otherwise you risk all sorts of awful debugging issues.

Comment: For throwing in `pdb.set_trace()` calls that should be taken out before you even think about shipping anything though, I think in-line import, in that narrow case where you are just copy/pasting in trace statements, is acceptable.

Comment: What's going on after that in your `while` loop and `if` statement?  You aren't by any chance changing the value of `rcv_record_len`, are you?

Comment: Could you add some useful print statements in here and tell us what they say?

Comment: I have to use pdb because I am trying to debug server code.
Also rcv_record_len does change as items are added an removed from the list. I can tell you that everything was working fine and the results were correct before I added this tmp.extend([first.Units_case])
#tmp.extend([(first.Units_case)/(first.Cost)])

Comment: If a Python error doesn't immediately make sense, it's almost always because you've got a syntax error or typo somewhere.  Unless you're pushing the boundaries of what python is capable of, or using a bleeding edge version of the engine, you will almost certainly *NEVER* experience a bug in the interpretter.

Comment: I am glad that people are so quick to point the finger at syntax but as I said earlier everything was working before I added those two lines of code. I have removed those to lines of code and commented the 5-6 lines that referenced them and everything works as it should.
Without the weird int list operand errors.

Comment: Can you just post stack traces for the failures you are getting?  Also, on a side note, why are you `extend`ing with a series of single-element lists instead of `append`ing?

Comment: Sure can ; P. I need to list to be in a certain form so that I can use template tags to access the data easier so that the html coding is more manageable. I know it's a wreck but it's my wreck :3

Comment: @user2482595 I think you need to post more - i.e. all - of your code.  Something is happening somewhere, and it doesn't seem to be in the code you've posted so far.

Comment: Or alternatively give us some useful information about the lines that seem to be "breaking everything" You're really not giving us anything to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got typo on each of the lines you've marked as a problem:

```
if rcv_record[rcv_record_len-1][6] <> first.Units_case or rcv_record[rcv_record-1][3] <> first.Cost: << THIS PIECE
```

Note the final index there, is `rcv_record - 1`, where `rcv_record` is a list.

Comment: Hah, go figure. I will have to take a look at it again I just commented that functionality out and ran with it. This is a problem to be sure but if it fixes the bug I will for sure give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's difficult to debug since you haven't posted the relevant piece of code, but from the error message I can tell you that for some reason or another `rcv_record_len` is a list. Post more of your code and I can give a more detailed answer. Maybe even fix your problem.

In general if you ever want to figure out what type an object is so that you can avoid problems like this in the future you can call something like this:

```
type(rcv_record_len)
>>> <type 'list'>
```

Or if you want to be a little more professional about it you should call `isinstance`

```
isinstance(rcv_record_len, list)
>>> True
```

Comment: Yeah I have found the issue it is in surrounding code BUT what I am doing is valid and kosher. Will post code.

Comment: @user2482595 Call me crazy, but something tells me that when you've got this kind of error, what you're doing is not quite kosher, and definitionally not valid.

Comment: No I can assure you it was working quite well until I added the last item to be extended to the list. As I ed-edited my post if I comment out a line of code all is well un-comment it and it breaks in random places.

Comment: `isinstance` isn't going to be as informative, because it will return `True` for `isinstance(B(), A)` when `class B(A): pass`.  `type(A())` is arguably better than `A().__class__` though.

Comment: @sr2222 That is definitely true, which is why I gave an example and mentioned that for actual testing isinstance is much more professional.

Comment: Well, if you want to be "professional" in Python, you should use duck-typing and avoid explicit type checking at all if at all possible.  :)

Comment: Use `type` - not `__class__`

Comment: @sr2222 true, hasattr() would probably be even better, but that seemed a little out of scope.